# Generate Orchard CMS Autoroutes based on hierarchical menu

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, url, razor, orchardcms

I have a set of custom content type pages in Orchard that are set up in an advanced menu like so:

Title: Parent Page
Position: 1

Title: Child Page
Position: 1.1

Title: Grandchild Page
Position: 1.1.1

Right now each has a URL that reflects the name (eg., /parent-page, /child-page, /grandchild-page).

How can I get the URLs for my custom content types to generate hierarchical urls (eg., /parent-page, /parent-page/child-page, /parent-page/child-page/grandchild-page) automatically?

-Carson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a token for the parent, you can do what taxonomies are doing for their default alias pattern.
Which brings me to the objection I would have to the actual question. It should not be the navigation that models the structure of contents but rather the structure of the contents that is reflected in the menu. So I would start with a good taxonomy of the contents and generate navigation from that. Your URLs would be right immediately if you did that.

Comment: Could you edit your answer and give a thorough explanation for structuring pages using taxonomies?

Comment: What do you mean? That's what taxonomies are doing: including your contents in a hierarchy of terms. See http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Orchard-TV#GettingStartedWithTaxonomies for an introduction to taxonomies.

Comment: I've watched your video before even posting this, and it doesn't seem to address my issue.  I want all of my pages to be hierarchical, the page titles to show up as links in a hierarchical menu, and have clean URLs to match, not have to create a new term for every single content page created, and then have to assign it to a term. In the demo you show, it appears that is how this module works.  Could you explain how to achieve this based on my question?

Comment: Use taxonomy terms as pages, by adding them a body part.

Comment: They aren't the basic "Page" type with just a body part, they are advanced custom types with many fields/parts.

Comment: I also have many different content types that will need to exist inside of the menu/taxonomy.

Comment: So add all those parts as well. As for those other types, what exactly is the problem with them?

Comment: There is no problem with the other types.  How do I get 6+ custom content types into your solution with the taxonomy?  All different combinations of custom types exist as parents/children of each other, and need to be shown with a hierarchy of at least 3 deep.

Comment: You can have more than one taxonomy. Each taxonomy creates its own term content type, that you can edit at will.
But really, if you don't like this approach, you can also use the container and containable parts.

Comment: Marking this answer for lack of better answers.

Comment: @Carson, did you decide to use Taxonomies or something else?  I have this same issue and I am trying to determine the best method.  The site I'm working on is a static marketing site (no blogs) which each page is related to a specific menu item (e.g. About/Team, About/Contact, etc.).