# What's the recommended approach for hierarchical URLs in Orchard?

Tags: orchardcms

I'd like to have a hierarchical URL structure in my site. Something on these lines:

- tutorials

  - javascript

    - jquery

There should be a page at each level (`tutorials`, `tutorials/javascript` and `tutorials/javascript/jquery`). Obviously, using Taxonomies would help me organize my content in this manner, but how do I get Autoroute URLs generated for this scenario?

Bertrand Le Roy made a comment [on this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727931/generate-orchard-cms-autoroutes-based-on-hierarchical-menu) about using taxonomy terms as pages but it still doesn't seem to create the right URL structure for me. Am I missing something? Is there something specific I need to configure or enable to make this happen?

Are there any other approaches I can look at?

I was thinking of specifying the default route as something like {Content.Fields.Page.TaxonomyName}. It appears that this isn't really possible right now according to [this bug report](http://orchardtaxonomies.codeplex.com/workitem/69).

Comment: FWIW, I voted that bug up. Taxonomies need tokens.

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy Yup, they sure do. In the mean time, what do you think of using fields to do it like I described below? Is there a better way?

Comment: I don't like that it's not using CommonPart.Container but other than that it sounds fine. It's a workaround, and if it gets you unblocked...

Answer (score 4):

Here's an approach that seems to work without having to use taxonomies:

I added a `Content Picker` field called `ParentPage` to the `Page` content type and updated the `Page`'s Autoroute default to

```
{Content.Fields.Page.ParentPage.Content.Path}/{Content.Slug}
```

Now in each page I get to pick what the parent page is and the URL is constructed how I expect it. From what I remember of working with WordPress, I think this is pretty close to how it allows you to do this parent page thing, too.