# What is the ParentPath token in Orchard and how do I use it?

Tags: orchardcms

While reading the source to figure out [how to do hierarchical URLs in Orchard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13540933/whats-the-recommended-approach-for-hierarchical-urls-in-orchard), I came across this in `SlugTokens.cs`:

```
// /path/to/parent-item/
.Token("ParentPath", T("Parent Path"), T("The parent item's path and slug with an appended forward slash if non-empty"));
```

Where is this used? Do content types have a parent property that I can leverage for making hierarchies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if your content type has the Common part (and most should have it), there is a Container property. It's also available from tokens: `{Content.Container.Path}/{Content.Slug}` is the autoroute pattern for blog posts for example. I think it's equivalent to `{Content.ParentPath}/{Content.Slug}`.

Comment: That's interesting. I don't see a UI for setting this container property for any content type. So if I were to add that UI and set the container for, say the Page content type, then I would effectively be able to get a parent/child hierarchy among pages. Am I getting it right or am I thinking about this the wrong way?

Comment: There *is* UI that surfaces it: the Containable part. You need to set it up on your content type if you want that capability. There is an associated Container part. Usually you don't need to because the container property is being managed in code for most content types where it makes sense.